# Delete an object based on property

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have two arrays.

```
_ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS = []; // Array of objects with a property useruid
pastLikedUsersArray = []; // Array of strings
```

I want to delete an object from the _ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS if one of the objects has a property value that is in the pastLikedUsersArray string.

I have a for loop that iterates through the length of both arrays and then this splice method below.

```
_ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS.splice(pastLikedUsersArray[j], 1);
```

However, I think it is comparing an object to a string and thus not deleting. How can I achieve what I want?

I also tried:

```
_ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS[i].useruid.splice(pastLikedUsersArray[j], 1);
```

This did not work

useruid is one of the properties in the _ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS and the values are strings, the likes of which could be in the other array. 
I got an error saying it was not a function.

In fact, after more digging, it appears it is deleting one but not the correct one which is very strange

Comment: First argument to splice should be index of the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
for (var i=0; i<_ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS.length; i++) {
   if (pastLikedUsersArray.indexOf(_ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS[i].useruid) != -1) {
      _ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
   }
}
```

or using filter:

```
_ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS = _ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS.filter(function(user) {
     return pastLikedUsersArray.indexOf(user.useruid) != -1;
});
```

Comment: this looks promising. which part should i console.log out to see which one got deleted?

Comment: In the first one you should `console.log(_ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS[i])` on the second one I think you can't see which one was removed but you can run `console.log(_ARRAY_OF_FUTURE_USERS.slice())` before filter and after and check the difference.